# Zabbix Database Upgrade fails. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, zabbix

Changed the content:

Looks like Zabbix during its database upgrade it creates a TMP table, Copies data fromt the Original table to TMP table, Drops the original table, creates a new table with Constraint, tries to copies the data from tmp table to thew new table and fails. I removed the contrasting for the trigger_discovery table and it got updated and then it jumped to graph_discovery and failed. I'll add the constraint back, but why is this failing and what needs to be done?

Zabbix LOGS:

```
query:   [create table graph_discovery_tmp (graphid bigint unsigned not null,parent_graphid bigint unsigned not null) engine=innodb]
query:   [update dbversion set mandatory=2030012,optional=2030012]
query:   [insert into graph_discovery_tmp (select graphid,parent_graphid from graph_discovery)]
query:   [update dbversion set mandatory=2030013,optional=2030013]
query:   [drop table graph_discovery]
query:   [update dbversion set mandatory=203001,optional=203001]
query:   [create table graph_discovery (graphid bigint unsigned not null,parent_graphid bigint unsigned not null,primary key (graphid)) engine=innodb]
query:   [update dbversion set mandatory=2030015,optional=2030015]
query:   [create index graph_discovery_1 on graph_discovery (parent_graphid)]
query:   [ update dbversion set mandatory=2030016,optional=2030016]
query:   [alter table graph_discovery add constraint c_graph_discovery_1 foreign key (graphid) references graphs (graphid) on delete cascade]
query:   [update dbversion set mandatory=2030017,optional=2030017]
query:   [alter table graph_discovery add constraint c_graph_discovery_2 foreign key (parent_graphid) references graphs (graphid)]
query:   [update dbversion set mandatory=2030018,optional=2030018]
query:   [insert into graph_discovery (select graphid,parent_graphid from graph_discovery_tmp)]
query failed:   [1452] Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`zabbix`.`graph_discovery`, CONSTRAINT `c_graph_discovery_1` FOREIGN KEY (`graphid`) REFERENCES `graphs` (`graphid`) ON DELETE CASCADE) [insert into graph_discovery (select graphid,parent_graphid from graph_discovery_tmp)]
query:   [insert into graph_discovery (select graphid,parent_graphid from graph_discovery_tmp)] failed, setting transaction as failed
   database upgrade failed
   End of DBcheck_version():FAIL
```

Comment: So you obviously know the issue, trigger_discovery.triggerid is getting an insert or update and the parent does not exist. So it is not something that *you* are doing, rather you want us to help you debug some random update/upgrade logic ??

Comment: I wrote about update/upgrade because stackoverflow won't let me post without writing more content than just code, and I'm not good at writing, could not find words. Besides I've already found a solution, still testing (had to insert data from discovery_tmp table to triggers). If all good, I'll answer my own question and post the solution

Comment: Cool Arvind. I hope all is well then.

Answer (score 1):

### Zabbix 2.2 up to 2.4

/var/log/zabbix-server/zabbix_server.log

[Z3005] query failed: [1452] Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`zabbix`.`graph_discovery`, CONSTRAINT `c_graph_discovery_1` FOREIGN KEY (`graphid`) REFERENCES `graphs` (`graphid`) ON DELETE CASCADE) [insert into graph_discovery (select graphid,parent_graphid from graph_discovery_tmp)]

```
use zabbix; 
DROP TABLE graph_discovery;
CREATE TABLE `graph_discovery` (
        `graphid` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
        `parent_graphid` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (graphid)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```